# How to give relative path for my file in java file?

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, tomcat

I am using tomcat server for my java application(Servlet,jsp).In my servlet page  calling one java class function.Actually the java file is written separately and i will call the function written inside it.With in the function, i have to read one config(user defined) file for some purpose.so, i am using File class for that.

But, here i have to give relative path of the config file(user defined).Because, now i am running this application in local windows server.But my live server is based on Linux.So, the file path is changed in linux.

```
File f1=new File("D:\tomcat\webapp\myapp\WEB-INF\src\point_config.txt");  -- windows
File f1=new File("D:\ravi\tomcat\webapp\myapp\WEB-INF\src\point_config.txt");  -- linux
```

So, i have to give relative path of the file that is common to both windows and linux machine.

Is there a way to do this?

Please guide me to get out of this issue?

Comment: Is that file in your classpath or directly under web-inf?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Place your config file under your webapp WEB-INF/classes folder and read like this in code

```
InputStream is= 
   YourClassName.class.getResourceAsStream("point_config.txt");
```

Answer (score 1):

The path of the config file leads into the WEB-INF folder

```
tomcat\webapp\myapp\WEB-INF\src\point_config.txt
```

Anything inside WEB-INF is protected and cannot be user-defined once the web application has launched. If you meant to read from a user-defined configuration file from the file system, please use an API like the [common configuration API](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-configuration/).

If you want to insist on keeping the file inside the WEB-INF folder, use the `Class.getResourceAsStream()` method to obtain the configuration instead. That would not make the configuration user-defined though.

Comment: Are you sure the application can't reach inside WEB-INF?  Can you provide a source for the statement regarding protection?  I know a user can't hit a file inside WEB-INF, but I believe the application can.

Comment: @KevinBowersox No, the application CAN reach inside WEB-INF through `Class.getResourceAsStream()`. The user cannot reach inside WEB-INF. I mentioned that to stress that a property inside WEB-INF is not really user-defined.